# What was irreligious in the marriage between Krishna's grandson and Rukmi's grand daughter?

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana, puri-shankaracharya, rukmini

Please see the attached verses from [Bhagvatam](https://archive.org/details/bhagavatapuranagitapress_201907/page/n1244/mode/1up)

Carumati was Krishna's daughter who married Krtavarma's son. Her son Aniruddha married Rocana. Rocana was Rukmavati and Pradyumna's daughter and Rukmi's grand daughter.

Question is why did Rukmi consider this alliance as "contrary to the principles of piety" ?

Bhagvatam is silent behind the reasons. So I am looking for commentaries of traditional acharyas or references from Smritis.

Pls note that ISKCON's [commentary](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/61/25/) says it is because of the following injunctions

> dviṣad-annaṁ na bhoktavyaṁ dviṣantaṁ naiva bhojayet. “One should not eat an enemy’s food or feed an enemy.” There is also the following prohibition: asvargyaṁ loka-vidviṣṭaṁ dharmam apy ācaren na tu. “One should not execute religious injunctions if they will obstruct one’s journey to heaven, or if they are odious to human society.”

If the above is indeed the case then can someone share link to the scriptures where these injunctions are mentioned.

And finally how did Sri Krishna justify the alliance. Bhagvatam says Rukmi did it because of love for his sister, and perhaps met his end because of going against scripture injunctions( dining with enemy). But why did Sri Krishna go against these injunctions ?

Puri Shankaracharya [says](https://youtu.be/OYh5l1URJcM) Krishna knew about adharma ( around 2:30 minute mark) but only agreed to it as he didn't want a Mahabharata in his household. He too refers to Bhagvatam but I am unable to find reference.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133235/discussion-on-question-by-carmen-sandiego-what-was-irreligious-in-the-marriage-b).